# How to compare 2 classifiers after testing trained model in Weka?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I'm new to Weka (and machine learning) so this question would be a bit silly.

So I have 2 models built using J48 and RandomForest (both run with 10-fold cross-validation mode) on a 40,000-tuple training set. I also have 6 different smaller test sets, each has around 8000 tuples.

Now I want to compare how these 2 classification algorithms perform after testing their models (I have the predictions reported).

The problem is, I don't have a good understanding of the reported predictions so I don't know how to compare the prediction of each to see which one is better in terms of accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

For classifier comparison, you can usually set up a paired experiment. That is, look at predictions of the same case by both models instead of at overall precision of the models.

[McNemar's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test) in Wikipedia (or here) should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

What determines the performance of your classification systems? Success rate? AUC? F-measure? and so on. This wiki page is reasonable for an introduction on all of that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic.

WEKA reports most of these measures quite clearly (in the summary output), and you can use a ThresholdCurve to plot ROC curves.

Once you've decided that, confidence intervals and the paired t-test are commonly used.

These slides aren't bad also: http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~tgd/classes/534/slides/part13.pdf